# How to include a dependency that is not an angular module in gulp-Angular yeoman generator?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, generator, bower, yeoman

I'm using a yeoman generator called "[gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular)", I'm trying to add a dependency that is not an angular module, this dependency is a jquery plugin. I include this dependecy with: `bower install depdency_name --save"` but when I try to use it, I get an error, this error is a 404.

For a concrete example: I'm trying to include this dependency: [blurry-image-load](https://github.com/tushariscoolster/blurry-image-load)

So, when I want to include something dependency that is not an angular module, what I need to do, to make it work?

Thanks for your time

Comment: We don't know what you're doing. We don't know your code. We have a very vague idea of what the error is. How could we help?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because the module you are trying to get isn't available in Bower.

You can however specify a full URL in Bower instead of a Bower package name. The URL should point to the main JavaScript file in their GitHub repo.

PS don't forget to add the script tag in the head of your HTML file.